# JSON Arrays with Same Identifier in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to iterate through an array to grab each unique value of 5 objects that are named the same thing ("fullimage"). I will need to use the "fullimage" identifier to iterate through each image. Below is an example of the array. I've been able to display all "fullimage" objects of the array as one long string, but not a specific one only.

{"$id":"1", "images":[{"$id":"2","fullimage":"image1.jpg"}, {"$id":"3","fullimage":"image2.jpg"}, {"$id":"4","fullimage":"image3.jpg"}, {"$id":"5","fullimage":"image4.jpg"}, {"$id":"6","fullimage":"image5.jpg"}] }

I've filtered my datasource to a specific item, so in this case "filteredItem" in my code below will have filtered it to "$id":"1". This line of code below displays all "image.jpg" objects as one long string.

---

{this.state.filteredItem.filter(item => item.images.map(item => item.fullimage))}

---

This would display: image1.jpgimage2.jpgimage3.jpgimage4.jpgimage5.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just `this.state.filteredItem.images.map(item => item.fullimage)`? That will return an array of strings.

If you want you can map that into an array of components.

Comment: When I try this I get an error. "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.filteredItem.images.map')".

Comment: Which part is undefined?

Comment: Not sure, that was the entire error. However I did figure out a solution. The image $id object occurs after ever item I filter to, so I'm able to add 1 to the id I'm on to further filter it:  this.state.filteredItem.map(item => item.images.filter(item => item.$id == (this.state.filteredItem.map(item => item.$id +1))).map(item => item.fullimage)))